# Right Shift Operator functionality in Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

`int z = -1; int m = z>>1; System.out.println("the values is " +m);`

Output is 
`the values is -1`

but my doubt is how it happening internally, Can any explain? Step by step procedure.

int z = 2; int m = z>>1;

the z value in binary

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010` ,

After the value is shifted then the m value in binary will be as

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001` , when I print `m` value it will be as `1`, but my question is, what is happening if I use negative value for z variable and when I assign z value with -1 why output variable has -1 itself? ( Two complement will happen are not?)

Comment: What do you mean how it happens internally? The right-shift operator is explained in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19). What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Requests for "step by step" anything are generally requests for a new full tutorial written to a specification. That feels like you're not doing any work at all, and asking for a lot of volunteer effort from someone else. A good tip on Stack Overflow is to show you have made a good effort, and if you cannot show that in a question, make more of an effort first.

Answer (score 0):

As described [in JLS Sec 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> The value of `n >> s` is `n` right-shifted `s` bit positions with sign-extension. The resulting value is `floor(n / 2^s)`.

So, you are calculating `-1 >> 1 == floor(-1 / 2) == floor(-0.5) = -1`.

Comment: `int z = 2; int m = z>>1;` the z value in binary ` 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 ` , After the value is shifted then the m value in binary will be as ` 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 ` , when I print m value it will be as `1`, but my question is, what is happening if I use negative value for `z` variable and when I assign `z` value with `-1` why output variable has `-1` itself? ( Two complement will happen are not?)

Comment: @Prakash you should maybe read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift#Non-equivalence_of_arithmetic_right_shift_and_division, as it describes this specific case (albeit in 8-bit).